# Giving different ID to dynamically created button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a set of textboxes using jQuery and give them ids. I need give id only textboxes.

It doesn't have to be the same ids I gave right now, there may be other. I couldn't figure out how. Is there can any help?

```
var cT = '<hr>';
cT += ' <div id="divMessageProfile"></div>';
cT += ' <div class="form-group" id="modalStockAdd" >';
cT += ' <div class="row">'
cT += ' <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9" >';
cT += ' <label class="pull-left">Barkod No</label> ';
cT += ' </div >';
cT += ' <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3" >';
cT += ' <label class="pull-left">Adet</label> ';
cT += ' </div >';
cT += ' </div >';
cT += ' <div class="row">'
cT += ' <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9" >';
cT += ' <input type="text" id="txtBarkod" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Barkod No Giriniz"> ';
cT += ' </div >';
cT += ' <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3" >';
cT += ' <input type="text" id="txtPiece" class="form-control border-input pull-left" placeholder="Adet Giriniz"> ';
cT += ' </div >';
cT += ' </div >';
cT += ' </div >';

jQuery(document).on('click', '#btnContinue', function () {
    $('#modalStockAdd').append(
          ' <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9" >'
        + ' <label class="pull-left">Barkod No</label> '
        + ' </div >'
        + ' <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3" >'
        + ' <label class="pull-left">Adet</label> '
        + ' </div >'
        + ' </div >'
        + ' <div class="row">'
        + ' <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-9" >'
        + ' <input type="text" id="txtBarkod" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Barkod No Giriniz"> '
        + ' </div >'
        + ' <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3" >'
        + ' <input type="text" id="txtPiece" class="form-control border-input pull-left" placeholder="Adet Giriniz"> '
        + ' </div > '
    )
});
```

Comment: better to use class instead of id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understadn you right this will do the job for you just adapt it for your html

```js
var number = 0;

$('button').on("click", function(){
  var html = '<p>number '+number+'</p>'
  $('#message').append(html);
  number++
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Append</button>
 <div id="message"></div>
```